# How to customize the way objects/resources load from my website created with Joomla?

Tags: resources, joomla, loading, customization

Suppose I want the browser to load an image right on the first connection it makes to my website. How do I do that, considering that by default the image loads later on when it's actually called for?

Also, after the whole page finishes loading, suppose I want to load more objects (say images) that aren't required yet but are just for buffer. How do I do that? Help me people, I've been at it for quite a long time.

I'm somewhat successful with the first problem by adding a script tag while actually calling an image at the beginning of my index.php's html head part which goes like:

```
<script src="http://www.mysite.com/my/image/url.png"></script>
```

But this I realize is bad scripting.

As for "Why would you want to do that?", it's for educational purposes and also because when someone visits my site, I need to load and display certain things before other things get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For preloading you probably could start with

```
<body onLoad="Preload('image1.jpg', 'image.gif', 'image.png', ...)">
```

And preload is a JavaScript function which adds each of the array of images to DOM like

```
document.imageArray[i].src = args[i];
```